# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ why?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, httpresponse

I have a problem, getting

```
 Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

and I don't know how to solve it?

this is the API-end point

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
    @POST("/api/register")
    Call<User> register(@Field("name") String name,
                               @Field("email") String email,
                               @Field("national_id") String national_id,
                               @Field("phone") String phone,
                               @Field("password") String password,
                               @Field("password_confirmation") String password_confirmation);
```

and here is the call

```
 EndPoints Api = RetrofitCreation.getInstance();
            Call<User> call = Api.register(full_name, email, id, phone, password,password2);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                    Log.e("register success",response.message().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            response.body().toString() +"",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("register fail", t.getMessage().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                             t.getMessage()  ,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
```

the User class :

```
public class User {
public int id;
public String name;
public String national_id;
public String phone;
public int role_id;
public String email;
```

}

and finally, the response should be like this:
[image: response from post man]

Comment: You wrote what response should be, but is it actually like on attached link?

Comment: you should use HttpLoggingInterceptor with your retrofit object, it will show you how your app pass your request. it will also show you response, so that you can detect actual problem form that

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Json2Pojo](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to convert your JSON to a serializable or parcelable class. and don't forget to implement GSON library inside your app's  Build.Gradle